# std::get_time on Windows fails with dates past 2036 -01-01

Tags: c++, std

I am getting a strange behaviour on Windows for the std::get_time function. 
The following code results in an empty expirationTm variable when the date in dateStr is 2036-01-01 or later.

```
string dateStr = "2035-12-01";    
expirationTm.tm_mday = 0;
expirationTm.tm_mon = 0;
expirationTm.tm_year = 0;
expirationTm.tm_wday = 0;
expirationTm.tm_yday = 0;
expirationTm.tm_sec = 0;
expirationTm.tm_min = 0;
expirationTm.tm_hour = 0;
expirationTm.tm_isdst = 0;
istringstream ss(dateStr);
ss >> std::get_time(&expirationTm, "%Y-%m-%d");
```

Nothing I saw in the documentation suggests that get_time does not supports dates past 2036.
Is this a known bug ?

Comment: Reading about the [year 2036](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2036) might give you a hint.

Comment: Thanks ! I also learned about [John Titor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Titor) today but it doesn't really solve my problem :)

Comment: More specifically it's the bullet-point about NTP and the 1900 epoch that's the important thing. And no, it doesn't really help you but it does explain the problem you're having.

Comment: Yeah I figured they had to keep this behaviour for compatibility reasons. Does this mean the same behaviour is to be expected on UNIX based platforms ?

Comment: POSIX use 1970-01-01 as the epoch, so it will handle 2036 without problems, but only by [about two years](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem).